# Start a task process (Get user)

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow, tasks, approval-process

I am using "start a task process" to generate an approval task. The task is assigned to several users (so "assign task" is not an option) but is configured so that the first response is the good one.

Inside the workflow I need to know which user gives that first response so that I can assign him/her another task.

Is there any way to do that? (without developing anything)

Tehcnologies: Sharepoint 2013 + Project Server

Thanks!